# Opening a CSV file with a particular permission in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write some output in CSV file from my python program. I wanted to open the new CSV file with the permission as 666 but I am not able to do it.
I know I can do the same with OS module of python but I am avoiding it.
Is there anyway that we can set the permission of the CSV at the time of creation itself without use of any other module. I am using 'CSV' module in python for csv creation.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.3
import csv
x = open('tmpfile1.csv','wb')
x.close()
```

Here instead of 'wb', can I use some parameter so that the permission is set to 666 (Linux).

Comment: @Selcuk It definitely is not a duplicate. The answer in the link you provided has used OS module which I do not want to use. I request for a solution which sets the permission as 666 in the open command itself without using any other module. Thanks!

Comment: Reading the documentation of the open() command the only options available are outside of what you are asking. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) It might be some confusion between what file permissions (*access rights*) and *access modes* (r/w/a/r+/w+/a+/rb/wb/ab...) are but I don't think you can achieve what you are asking inside the "open()" command.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can open a file in r+ mode to perform Read and Write operation.

```
infile = open('myfile.txt','r+')
```